# wpf 4.5 controls are slow, have lag

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, xaml, wpf-4.0

I have a wpf 4.5 application where I am trying to trouble shoot why my controls are slow, or have lag with the user input.  If a user tabs between control, like textboxes, or changes the text of a textbox there is a serious lag between the user typing and the text appearing in the text box.

For example:
A textbox declaration

```
<TextBox x:Name="chrTitle" 
         Style="{StaticResource FTC_ValidateTextBox}" 
         Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding chrTitle, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**I thought it might be the validation so:** I have tried removing the ValidatesOnDataErrors and changing the UpdateSourceTrigger to lostfocus, property changed and explicit.  With no improvement.

**I thought it might be a style or binding related issue so:** I also set the style to x:Null and I removed the binding al together, both also gave no improvement.

This affects other controls like drop downs.

### Question:

Can someone help me trouble shoot what in my application is causing input lag with controls like textboxes and dropdowns.

Comment: Are you sure its your application, does this happen on all machines, in release build, could be GFX card/driver related since WPF is Hardware accelerated

Comment: Thanks @sa_ddam213, its the same in release and I created a blank wpf project with some controls and they all respond fine.  So that leads me to believe it is my application (but I could easily be worng).  Maybe my resources or styles are the problem, but I am not sure how to debug the performance of visual elements / rendering in WPF.

Comment: In my experience broken bindings, unstopped storyboards and inefficient command CanExecute functions can cause slowdowns, if you have VisualStudios Analyze menu (or download a free trial of a Profiling tool) run a profile of your application to find the "Hot spots"

Comment: @sa_ddam213, you were right.  I had no broken bindings and there are no animations.  But I had 6 can execute commands, I commented them all out and the performance issue is solved.  So I guess I have to make them more efficient. Post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with slow WPF applications, common causes can be:

1. broken bindings,
2. unstopped storyboards
3. inefficient command CanExecute functions

This would be the first place to start